# Can't connect to database xampp in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp-vm

I have used laravel before when it was 5.4 and I could easily connect to database, Now I want to work in a new project. try to connect to database and get this error.

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = todo and table_name = migrations)
```

I have tried every single trick I have found on stackoverflow. NONE worked.
Why is this happening? this is my connection.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=todo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Comment: can you try to connect your database with 3rd party database manager software by typing this credentials ?

Comment: could you pls be more specific, don't what you talking about. thanks

Comment: can you use mysql tool to connect database such us `sequel pro` or some mysql gui tool

Comment: I am using xammp, don't have seguel pro or else. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the `DB_HOST` with the actual ip address instead like

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=todo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

Comment: tried that one, like I said, I have tried every single trick I found here in stackoverflow. It used to be so easy to migrate.

Comment: Ok. It was too obvious I suppose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on VM? If that case then try to point the DB_HOST to the right IP address of your Xampp SQL and then do php artisan *config:cache* & *config:clear*